# How do you utilize array output from OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

Python beginner here...

Trying to understand how to use OneHotEncoder from the sklearn.preprocessing library. I feel pretty confident in using it in combination with fit_transform so that the results can also be fit to the test dataframe. Where I get confused is what to do with the resulting encoded array. Do you then convert the ohe results back to a dataframe and append it to the existing train/test dataframe?

The ohe method seems a lot more cumbersome than the pd.get_dummies method, but from my understanding using ohe with fit_transform makes it easier to apply the same transformation to the test data.

Searched for hours and having a lot of trouble trying to find a good answer for this.

Example with the widely used Titanic dataset:

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
imp = SimpleImputer()

ct = make_column_transformer(
    (imp, ['Age']),
    (ohe, ['Sex', 'Embarked']),
    remainder='passthrough')
ct.fit_transform(train)
```

Result:

```
array([[22.        ,  0.        ,  1.        , ...,  1.        ,
         0.        ,  7.25      ],
       [38.        ,  1.        ,  0.        , ...,  1.        ,
         0.        , 71.2833    ],
       [26.        ,  1.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  7.925     ],
       ...,
       [29.69911765,  1.        ,  0.        , ...,  1.        ,
         2.        , 23.45      ],
       [26.        ,  0.        ,  1.        , ...,  0.        ,
         0.        , 30.        ],
       [32.        ,  0.        ,  1.        , ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  7.75      ]])
```

Do you pass the resulting array directly into a variable, for example X and y for train_test_split to run the final models off of? Or is there a way to convert the result back to a dataframe with column labels for further EDA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: `pandas.get_dummies()` is a lot easier to use, but the advantage of using OHE is that it will always apply the same transformation to unseen data. You can also export the instance using `pickle` or `joblib` and load it in other scripts.

There may be a way to directly reattach the encoded columns back to the original `pandas.DataFrame`. Personally, I go about it the long way. That is, I fit the encoder, transform the data, attach the output back to the DataFrame and drop the original column.

```py
# Columns to encode
cols = ['Sex','Embarked']

# Initialize encoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder()

# Fit to data
ohe.fit(df[cols])

# Declare encoded data as new columns in `df`
df[ohe.get_feature_names] = ohe.transform(df[cols])

# Drop unencoded columns
df.drop(cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Finally, I noticed you said:

> I feel pretty confident in using it in combination with fit_transform so that the results can also be fit to the test dataframe.

I would like to point out that you should **not** fit the encoder again!  Rather, you should use `ohe.transform(X_test[cols])` when dealing with new data. Do not use `fit_transform()` again or the results may vary from one dataset to another.

Comment: Thank you Arturo! Yes, I'm glad you pointed out as to not fit the test data again. It seems like there are a lot of advantages to using OneHotEncoder but I rarely see it implemented.